# Converting a string of a byte to an unsigned int

Tags: c++

For an application I'm trying to write I need to be able to write GLEnable(GL_REPEAT) in an interface (got this working).
Once the user does that, the system should call the function with the correct parameter.

So far, I've got the correct function being called

`((void (*)(unsigned int)) FunctionName)(Parameter);` but with the parameter of 0.

In order to get the correct parameter, I am reading the glew.h file as a text file, and parsing it into an std::map. However, I am stuck on how to convert 0x2901 (and the rest) from a string to an unsigned int. If anyone happens to know how to do this, help would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks in advance,

Joey

Comment: [std::stoul](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoul/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could use a `std::stringstream`:

```
std::string hexString = "0x2901";
std::istringstream instream(hexString);
unsigned int receiver = 0;
instream >> std::hex >> receiver;
std::cout << "Value parsed: " << receiver << std::endl;
std::cout << "Should be 10497" << std::endl;
```

Output:

> Value parsed: 10497 
>   Should be 10497

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/feb9af9bc4fd74b0)

Comment: Thanks, this works great :)
Still don't have it working though, but that's due to the void* function with a parameter. This part works :)

Comment: @JoeyvanGangelen: Glad it works. Please accept this answer if it solved your issue. 

If you have another issue regarding your `void*` function, you may consider asking a separate question.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow.. How do I accept the answer? I checkmarked it on the left, but can't find a "mark as solved" or anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can try also C style (`sscanf` function), like that:

```cpp
    std::string hex = "0x2901";
    unsigned int x;
    sscanf(hex.c_str(), "%x", &x);
    printf("%#X = %u\n", x, x);
```

`sscanf` allows checking in the following style:

```cpp
    std::string hex = "0x2901";
    unsigned int x = 0;
    if ( sscanf(hex.c_str(), "%x", &x) == 1) 
    {
        printf("%#X = %u\n", x, x);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Incorrect string value\n");
    }
```